# Dynamic Content of the layout page in Grails

Tags: grails

Imagine you layout page of your grails application has some dynamic content that gets update on each page request. When a page is requested, the controller that is requested has nothing to do with the dynamic data provided by the main.gsp page. How should I manage this?

I mean when a page is requested, how do I update the dynamic portion of the layout portion that the page controller is agnostic about? Plus I do not want to put layout dynamic code is every controller.

Comment: So essentially there is data that has to be used in every GSP you have, and you want to avoid having to pass it down in every controller?

Comment: You can do normal code in GSPs, however I doubt it is the best solution. Do this with `<% Map data = [:] %>`.

Comment: Actually I mean some of the data in main gsp has to come from a remote service call but I do not want to make every controller of mine to call this web service and all the data to the model for data update of the layout page. I mean I want to somehow make the layout page to be responsible for its dynamic data update but I can not have two controller for one page. Is there a better to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able create a [TagLib](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#taglibs) for this.

```
grails create-tag-lib myLayout
```

Then make your taglib responsible for the remote service calls.  You can do pretty much anything in a taglib that you can to in a controller, and you can also call any Grails services you've already created.

```
class MyLayoutTagLib {
    static namespace = "myLayout"
    def stockQuoteService

    def getStockPrice = { attrs ->     
        out <<  stockQuoteService.getLatestPrice(attrs.stockSymbol)
    }
}
```

Then in your gsp

```
<myLayout:getStockPrice stockSymbol="${user.favoriteStockSymbol}" />
```

Or however you get the relevant data to make the remote service call.